# Debian: How can I pull a single package with dependencies from another repository?

Tags: repository, debian, package, apt

I am on debian etch and I want to pull subversion1.5.1 from testing though it is a production machine. I need to keep the risk minimal.

Any hints?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just add the testing repository to your sources.list and pin the priority of the testing packages to a very low value:

Add the following to /etc/apt/preferences:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 200
```

200 means that new packages in testing still override local packages that are not in stable (local is always 100), but not ones that are in the stable repo as well.

Read apt_preferences(5) for more information on pinning.

Then, you can install packages from testing by doing

```
$ apt-get install -t testing $some_package
```

but they won't be installed by normal upgrade operations or won't be the default when installed with apt.

Comment: Of course this also works for Ubuntu. You'd just use an upcoming version's shorthand name (such as `trusty`) wherever `testing` is used in this recipe.

Comment: How do you keep this package up-to-date? From what I see, `apt-get upgrade` will ignore new versions available and you would have to install every update manually.